# Pass local res variable domain/protocol to view in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to pass a local variable to my view, which stores the protocol/domain. So something like: 'https://mywebsite.com', 'http://localhost:8000', etc'

In my express app, I'm passing a custom request object to the `res.locals` object

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.domain = req.protocol + '://' + req.headers.host;
    // outputs 'http://locahost:8000'
    console.log(res.locals.domain)
    next();
  });

  // middleware, etc

  // using angular
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
      request: req
    });
  });
```

In my view however, when I output `{{ domain }}`, it outputs `undefined`.

```
<p>{{ domain }}</p>
```

Comment: Show your code which actually renders a view. Usually you just add an object after the render call which contains values that the view can use.

Comment: I added the `app.get` call which renders the index page

Comment: Which templating engine are you using? And can you check if `res.locals` still makes sense right before the `res.render()`?

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        request: req,
        domain: res.locals.domain
    });
});
```

Domain can now be accessed because you added it to the object. Note: This now depends on your template/render engine - but your template/render engine now has access to the domain variable.

```
<p>{{ domain }}</p>
```

Comment: When I tried this, the `domain` variable stripped out the protocol. It outputted `//localhost:8000`

Comment: Guess there's three possibilities I can think of: 1. Your middleware is changing `res.local.domain`, 2. the render engine is removing `http:`, or 3. The client/browser is removing/hiding it somehow. I'd just `console.log` in the route to double check it's correct before calling `render`. If that's good, then use `curl`, `wget`, or view-source to get and look at the actual response.